# Trying to turn onclick to enter key

Tags: html, onclick

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to help some special education students with a very basic budget calculator. I've seen similar questions to mine posted, but when I try those methods something always breaks and I'm having some trouble figuring it out.

Basically I need the onclick portion of the button that calls the function into action to actually respond to the enter key and not a click :-( Thank you very much in advance for any help that might be provided!!

```
 <script>
    function addTwoNumbers () {
        var number1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
        var number2 = Number(document.getElementById('box2').value);
        var sum = Number(number1) + number2;
        document.getElementById('resultBox').value = sum;
        if(sum<0) {
            document.getElementById('resultBox').style.color = "red";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('resultBox').style.color = "green";
        }
        document.getElementById('resultBox').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('resultBox').value = sum
    }

</script>

<script>
    function subtractTwoNumbers () {
        var number1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
        var number2 = Number(document.getElementById('box2').value);
        var difference = Number(number1) - number2;
        document.getElementById('resultBox').value = difference;
        if(difference<0) {
            document.getElementById('resultBox').style.color = "red";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('resultBox').style.color = "green";
        }
        document.getElementById('resultBox').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('resultBox').value = sum
        
    }
</script>

<script>
    function clearall() {
        document.getElementById('box1').value = "";
        document.getElementById('box2').value = "";
        document.getElementById('resultBox').value = "";
    }
</script>
```

```
<div id='calc' align="center"></div>
<h1>Calculator</h1>
<p>Enter budget <input type="text" id="box1"></p>
<p>Enter price &ensp;  <input type="text" id="box2"></p>
<p>Press the equation key to see your results</p>   
<div class="btn-group" style="width:100%">
<button style="width:33.3%" onclick="addTwoNumbers()">+</button>
<button style="width:33.3%" onclick="subtractTwoNumbers()">-</button>
<p>
<button style="width:67.5%" onclick="clearall()">clear</button>
</div>  
<h3>Do you have enough?</h3>
<input type="text" id="resultBox"> <br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the onclick attribute in the HTML, a more modern approach would be to create an event listener in your javascript.

I would give the buttons an ID. Then do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("clearBtn").addEventListener("click", clearAll);
```

There are all kinds of events you can listen for and I would guess you could find one that provides the behavior you are after.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try giving that a shot